# Merge two files based on common string in column, and fill in missing values for mismatches

Tags: arrays, awk, merge

File 1:

```
rs30051 102098 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs44619 103300 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs62418 103585 1|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs33155 105222 0|1 1|0 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|1
```

File 2:

```
rs86792 101580 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|0
rs30051 102098 0|1 0|0 0|0 1|0
rs44619 103300 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs33155 105222 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 
rs27799 105943 0|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
```

The merged file needs to be sorted on column 2. All data from file 1 and file 2 must be retained in the output file. If (e.g.) a certain column 1 identifier is found in file 2, but not found in file 1, file 2 columns 1 and 2 are printed to the output file, followed by 6 x 0|0's for the missing values in file 1, followed by the 4 x values from file 2 (for the identifier not found in file 1). Desired output file:

```
rs86792 101580 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|0
rs30051 102098 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 1|0
rs44619 103300 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs62418 103585 1|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs33155 105222 0|1 1|0 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0
rs27799 105943 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
```

An awk command would be preferred and an explanation would be much appreciated. Filling in the missing values makes this question different than any I was able to find on this site. So far my code (which does not work):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file1 file2 | sort -k 2 > output.file
```

Answer (score 2):

If the first two columns are of fixed width similar to sample shown in the input, here's `awk+sort` solution. I tested it with `GNU` versions of these tools, but I feel it should work with other implementations too.

```
$ cat script.awk
{
    s1 = substr($0, 1, 14)
    s2 = substr($0, 15)
}

NR == FNR {
    a[s1] = s2
    next
}

{
    a[s1] = (s1 in a) ? a[s1] s2 : " 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0" s2
}

END {
    for (k in a) {
        s3 = (gsub(/\|/, "|", a[k])) == 6 ? " 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0" : ""
        print k a[k] s3
    }
}
```

Calling the script:

```sh
$ awk -f script.awk file1 file2 | sort -k2,2n
rs86792 101580 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|0
rs30051 102098 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 1|0
rs44619 103300 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs62418 103585 1|0 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0
rs33155 105222 0|1 1|0 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|1 0|0 0|0 1|0 0|0
rs27799 105943 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 1|1 0|0 0|0
```

If first two columns can vary in width, use this instead for `s1` and `s2`:

```
    s1 = $1 FS $2
    s2 = $0
    sub(/^[^ ]+ [^ ]+/, "", s2)
```